# Если слово заканчивается на определенную букву, то выполнять действие

Tags: python

Код должен пройтись по списку и если команда заканчивается на определенную букву, в данном случае это буква "а", то должен сработать определенный код. Но как я понял, я где-то допустил ошибку и код не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
teams = ["Рома", "Фиорентина", "Салернитана", "Милан"]

for team in teams:
    if team[:-1] == "а":
        print("Команда подходит")
```

Comment: Используйте `str.endswith()`  тоесть `if team.endswith("а")`:

Comment: если сравнение работает не так, как ожидается, самый простой способ выяснить причину - вывести на экран то, что сравнивается. Банальное ``print(team[:-1])`` сразу показало бы тебе твою ошибку. Учись элементарным способам отладки.

Answer (score 2):

Зачем вам двоеточие здесь `team[:-1]`? Вы ведь так обрезаете строку по последний символ (не включая). К примеру `print("Рома"[:-1])` выдаст `Ром`.

```
teams = ["Рома", "Фиорентина", "Салернитана", "Милан"]

for team in teams:
    if team[-1] == "а":
        print("Команда подходит")
```